# Multicasting from Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, kotlin, multicast

I want to use **multicasting on Android** on the local network (Android is the **server/publisher**). The problem is that even if I use the exact example code from  [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-broadcast-multicast) or the one from the book: *Jeff Friesen - Learn Java for Android Development*, the packets do NOT get to any other device on the local network. I use Wireshark for troubleshooting and I see those packets only if I remotely capture the Android's traffic. I used different ports, different multicast addresses (beginning with 231, 232, 239, ...), tried both DatagramSocket and MulticastSocket, manually setted the network interface, used MulticastLock, increased TTL, turned off the firewall, etc., but none of these recommendations worked for me.

Here's my sample code:

```
    doAsync {
        val group = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.114")
        val socket = DatagramSocket()

        while (true) {
            val msg = "hello world".toByteArray()
            val packet = DatagramPacket(msg, msg.size, group, 4239)
            socket.send(packet)
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
    }
```

and the Android manifest permissions (I added everything which should be related to multicasting):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I test the code on the physical device (Xiaomi Mi3, API 23), connected to the same Wi-fi as my developing machine. I can receive the packets only on the same device. I also tried to send broadcast messages and the broadcasting is working properly.

No errors, no warnings. Am I missing something?

Thank for help.